# Find diff between 2 object with nested class

Tags: java

I would like to check how to compare 2 Objects and each Object has nested class within. how can I compare the emp1 and emp2 without the compareTo() inside the Employee class. Do I have to use Reflection?

```
public class App{
    public void addEmployee(){
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setId(123);
        person1.setFirstName("FirstName");
        person1.setLastName("LastName");
    
    
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setPerson(person1);
        emp1.setPosition("Tester1");
        emp1.setSalary(1000);
        
        
        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setId(223);
        person2.setFirstName("FirstName2");
        person2.setLastName("LastName2");
    
    
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setPerson(person2);
        emp2.setPosition("Tester2");
        emp2.setSalary(2000);
        
        //how can I compare the emp1 and emp2 without the compareTo() inside the Employee class.
        
        
    }
}

public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

public class Employee{
    private Person person;
    private String position;
    private double salary;
}
```

Comment: why would you need reflection for this? just compare the results of the getters

Comment: or use a Comparator if you need to use it on a large scale.

Comment: Note that your Employee variables are all declared locally, within a method, and so those variables are not visible outside of the method, and so I'm not sure how you're planning on using any of this code.

Comment: Also, wouldn't Employee extend from Person? This is all somewhat confusing.

Comment: `Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)`